# How to make a ufunc output a matrix given two array_like operands (instead of trying to broadcast them)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ufunc

I would like to get a matrix of values given two `ndarray`'s from a `ufunc`, for example:

```
degs = numpy.array(range(5))
pnts = numpy.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2])
values = scipy.special.eval_chebyt(degs, pnts)
```

The above code doesn't work (it gives a `ValueError` because it tries to broadcast two arrays and fails since they have different shapes: (5,) and (3,)); I would like to get a matrix of values with rows corresponding to degrees and columns to points at which polynomials are evaluated (or vice versa, it doesn't matter).

Currently my workaround is simply to use `for`-loop:

```
values = numpy.zeros((5,3))
for j in range(5):
    values[j] = scipy.special.eval_chebyt(j, pnts)
```

Is there a way to do that? In general, how would you let a `ufunc` know you want an `n`-dimensional array if you have `n` array_like arguments?

I know about `numpy.vectorize`, but that seems neither faster nor more elegant than just a simple `for`-loop (and I'm not even sure you can apply it to an existent `ufunc`).

**UPDATE** What about `ufunc`'s that receive 3 or more parameters? trying `outer` method gives a `ValueError: outer product only supported for binary functions`. For example, `scipy.special.eval_jacobi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is exactly the [outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) method of ufuncs:

> ufunc.outer(A, B, **kwargs)
>
> ```
>   Apply the ufunc op to all pairs (a, b) with a in A and b in B.
> ```

```
values = scipy.special.eval_chebyt.outer(degs, pnts)
#array([[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
#      [ 0.    ,  0.1   ,  0.2   ],
#      [-1.    , -0.98  , -0.92  ],
#      [-0.    , -0.296 , -0.568 ],
#      [ 1.    ,  0.9208,  0.6928]])
```

**UPDATE**

For more parameters, you must broadcast by hand. [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) often help for that,spanning each parameter in a dimension. For exemple :

```
n=3
alpha = numpy.array(range(5))
beta =  numpy.array(range(3))
x = numpy.array(range(2))

data = numpy.meshgrid(n,alpha,beta,x)
values = scipy.special.eval_jacobi(*data)
```

Comment: I searched every possible search query except for "outer" keyword, although it definitely reminded me of the outer product operation. I should read more docs. Thank you!

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the problem seems harder than I thought. Please see the updated version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Reshape the input arguments for [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  In this case, change the shape of `degs` to be (5, 1) instead of just (5,).  The shape (5, 1) broadcast with the shape (3,) results in the shape (5, 3):

```
In [185]: import numpy as np

In [186]: import scipy.special

In [187]: degs = np.arange(5).reshape(-1, 1)  # degs has shape (5, 1)

In [188]: pnts = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2])

In [189]: values = scipy.special.eval_chebyt(degs, pnts)

In [190]: values
Out[190]: 
array([[ 1.    ,  1.    ,  1.    ],
       [ 0.    ,  0.1   ,  0.2   ],
       [-1.    , -0.98  , -0.92  ],
       [-0.    , -0.296 , -0.568 ],
       [ 1.    ,  0.9208,  0.6928]])
```

Comment: Awesome, this works for the case of 3 and more arguments as well. Thanks!